# How does one enforce aspects of a license?

Tags: licensing, enforcement

I've been provided a [SourceMod](http://www.sourcemod.net/) plugin for a community game server. I was provided the compiled plugin, but not the source code. The [license](https://svn.alliedmods.net/viewvc.cgi/trunk/public/licenses/LICENSE.txt?revision=2255&root=sourcemod) and [explanation](http://www.sourcemod.net/license.php) provided describes all SourceMod plugins as derivatives, meaning I should also receive a copy of the source.

How does one enforce such a requirement?

To be clearer, this is not about the SourceMod source code. That is available at the links I provided. This is about source code from the derived plugins made by a third party. The plugin is not listed on the SourceMod page, thus the source code is not available via their forums.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about law enforcement, which doesn't have much to do with the license being open source or not.

Comment: I also down vote this question, since the poster didn't make a good research effort. Source code is available in the Downloads area of the SourceMod website. Also law enforcement is not about licensing, IMHO.

Comment: @ecelis, it's not about SourceMod. It's about the plugin built using SourceMod. There is a very big difference. SourceMod is available at the link I provided. The plugins are provided by third party developers.

Comment: Are you asking how you, as the recipient, can enforce the requirement and obtain the source code? Or how the licensing party can enforce it on your behalf?

Comment: How can I obtain the source code?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen. Legal contracts and licenses are not laws; they are enforced by the signatories or licensors, respectively, not by law enforcement officers. This is our responsibility, and something we should be able to ask and answer questions concerning.

Comment: @Andy I see, and apologize for my mistake. How did you get the binary plugin? When I read how you edited the question, and your comment about how you can get the source code, then it depends. Which plugin is this? that'd help

Comment: The binary plugin was provided by the developer (and community member). It was custom built for us. However, the developer eventually left the community (not on the best of terms either...) and with that dropped support of the plugin. Unfortunately, several updates from Valve later, the plugin stopped functioning. It was at that point we realized we didn't have the source code.

Answer (score 7):

Enforcing any restrictions imposed is difficult, and ultimately you may have to bring it to legal proceedings.

The first step for any project, yours or someone else's, is to notify: if you spot something that doesn't comply, you should notify the project's author. They can deal with their own restrictions - you don't know if they've made an exception for this case or not. If you're the owner, your job is to notify the non-compliant: a polite email, simply saying you've noticed they don't do X and would they please do so, will suffice.

If you need to take it on further, there are various legal proceedings. Ultimately, the courts have your back because it's your work and someone is using it in a way they aren't permitted to. You may also be able to issue a DMCA takedown request, which is a legally-backed way of telling someone to remove something you don't want there. Assuming you have permission to do so.

Comment: Suggestion to improve this answer: mention organizations like the [Software Freedom Law Center](https://www.softwarefreedom.org/) that can help.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, in order to pursue legal action against someone, you need to have *standing* — that is, be a directly involved party. While there might be some legal theories that users of GPL-licensed software are intended beneficiaries of the license and therefore could make a case, I'm not aware of this ever having been tested anywhere. Lawsuits like those brought by [gpl-violations.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpl-violations.org) work because they directly involved a copyright holder — one of the people who granted use to their code via the GPL.

I'm not a lawyer, but you don't have to take my word for it; here is Eben Moglen writing for the Free Software Foundation:

> [...] despite the broad right of distribution conveyed by the GPL, enforcement of copyright is generally not possible for distributors: only the copyright holder or someone having assignment of the copyright can enforce the license.

Here, "distribution" is just one of the freedoms granted by the GPL, but the same basic concept applies to the others as well.

So that means that in this case, your best course of action is to contact the SourceMod authors and make them aware of the violation, and ask them to ask the module authors to comply.

Answer (score 1):

Enforcement is difficult.

First step would be to politely ask. The last step would be to bring it to court. The difficulty is to chose wisely the escalation steps in between and to decide when to stop.